# net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES error when adding numerous img elements to dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, backbone.js

I'm using jquery and backbone.js on a site that is pretty image heavy. The core functionality of the site involves many many fairly small images (150x180px jpg files). The list of images comes in via ajax/json using a backbone.js collection fetch. Then for each model in the collection there is a view that gets rendered which contains an img element. The view is then added to the dom.

There is one user in particular that has thousands of images - a super edge-case relative to how many images most of our normal users have. When this user's image data loads, the browser just can't handle loading all the images, at least in the way our current code works. About half of the images load okay eventually, but the browser (i'm using chrome 35) becomes unresponsive for several minutes. The other half of the images fail to load, and the browser console shows "net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES" errors for the images that don't load.

Here is the essential part of our code that loads the images. Can anyone provide an explanation as to technically why this image loading failure happens, and offer a solution **that doesn't involve adding paging or "click her to load more" functionality** to the image list?

```
// inside the view that renders the images
render: function () {
    this.collection.each(this.addOne, this);    
    return this;
},
addOne: function (imgModel) {
    var imgView = new App.Views.ImageView({ model: imgModel});
    this.$el.append(imgView.render().el);
}
```

And the render() code for the App.View.ImageView view:

```
render: function () {
    var renderedTemplate= theTemplate(this.model.toJSON());
    this.$el.html(renderedTemplate);
    return this;
}
```

And the template used by App.View.ImageView (this gets compiled only once using _.template):

```
<script type="text/template" id="thumb-template">          
        <a href="<%= ImageUrl%>"><img src="<%= ImageUrl%>" /></a>
        <div class="delete"></div>
</script>
```

Comment: Turns out that even though it is incredibly slow to load so many images, the strange error was coming from AdBlock Plus. I disabled that chrome plugin and the errors went away, and images load fine... just takes a long time for the browser to render the page and do all the work that the browser needs to do under the hood.

Comment: I know you said you didn't want a "click here to load more" solution but I have the same situation and I think infinite scrolling is probably the best option.  It makes sense too. Why force the browser to render 8k images at once when only ~20 of them will be seen by the user at a time?

Comment: @djKianoosh In my case the images are tiled and filtered visually using Isotope. You can't sort / filter items on the client-side that aren't loaded, hence I need all items to be loaded.

Comment: Ah I see.  In my case, I do the sorting/filtering on metadata, and displaying the images is decoupled from that. But I don't know Isotope so I can't say whether that's possible there.

Comment: The ad-block plus comment helped fix my issue too.

Answer (score 47):

I believe this is the bug affecting you: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=108055

There's been discussion about it from 2011-2016, and is ongoing. Basically Chrome can't handle a very large number of requests in a short period of time.

Here's what **helped a bit** for my app:

- You could add an event handler like
  `img.addEventListener("error",tryAgainLater)` but that won't rescue
  the other resources that fail to load, so your script that loading
  hundreds of images could interfere with others.
- Try to cache more of the images to reduce the number of network requests.
- Use Firefox instead... obviously can't tell customers that.

Here's what **did not work**:

- Compositing the images on to a canvas and discarding the individual images. This did not help because it's related to the network requests, not the images stored in memory.
- Not starting the next request until the previous image is fully loaded. Perhaps this is because it takes time for the connection to actually close or be removed from memory (or some other resource).

Yet to try:

- Loading the images over HTTP/2 or SPDY where there are many requests but only one connection.
- In your case you could probably inline the images to avoid making requests. Example from https://css-tricks.com/data-uris/ : `<img width="16" height="16" alt="star" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAABAALAAAAAAQABAAAAVVICSOZGlCQAosJ6mu7fiyZeKqNKToQGDsM8hBADgUXoGAiqhSvp5QAnQKGIgUhwFUYLCVDFCrKUE1lBavAViFIDlTImbKC5Gm2hB0SlBCBMQiB0UjIQA7" />`

Comment: Hi, FYI I tried "Loading the images over HTTP/2 where there are many requests but only one connection." but that results in the same problem. My test HTML tries to load 10000 images of 25x25 pixels.

Comment: Agreed -- we also tried HTTP/2 and it did not help.

Comment: The simplest solution is to just decrease the number of requests, by sending more data within each request. For example, it would be possible to zip multiple image files on the server and unzip them on the client side. I had this error in a Dropzone when sending a large file in chunks, and by increasing the chunk size I was able to lower the number of requests and avoid the ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES error.

Comment: As of mid-2018, [that bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=108055) has been fixed

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. For me i handled it by stoping subsequent requests after the first error and trying just a bit later with a timeout. Very patchwerk solution but it worked for a  quick fix(my case was just with a lot of data for exporting not images, so lazy loading really a solution)

Comment: what about using multiple thread with worker_threads on nodejs ?

Answer (score 5):

The method toJSON() is very expensive for the browsers as it clones the 'attributes' in the model to return a JSON representation.

```
...
// Return a copy of the model's `attributes` object.
toJSON: function(options) {
  return _.clone(this.attributes);
},
...
```

In some scenarios where I just wanted to display the information of my model, I simply used the 'attributes' property directly, it saves very good time of processing.

Try replacing this line in the ImageView file:

```
theTemplate(this.model.toJSON());
```

for

```
theTemplate(this.model.attributes);
```

Hope this information helps.