# Too much memory used

Tags: reactjs

I am making over 500 requests to an API with a different record number, checking whether response is something meaningful and, if yes, adding that record number to an array which is held in state. My issue is memory.. As soon as 7 record numbers are added to an array I am getting net::ERR_INSUFFICIENT_RESOURCES error in chrome. RAM usage jumps up to 2gb.. Why is that happening?

Code:

```
render(){
    this.state.records.map(record => {
        axios.get(`https://*some url*code=${record.A}&exactMatch=true`)
        .then(response => {
            if(response.data.mResponseData.filter.brand.length !== 73){
                this.setState({
                    validCount: this.state.validCount+1,
                    valid: [...this.state.valid, record.A],
                    checked: this.state.checked+1
                })
            }
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
            this.setState({
                errorsCount: this.state.errorsCount+1,
                errors: [...this.state.errors, record.A],
                checked: this.state.checked+1
            })
        })
    })
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>Valid count</h1>
            <p>{this.state.validCount}</p>
            <h1>Valids</h1>
            <ul>{this.state.valid.map(valid => {
                return(<li key={valid}>{valid}</li>);
            })}</ul>
            <h1>Errors count</h1>
            <p>{this.state.errorsCount}</p>
            <h1>Errors</h1>
            <ul>{this.state.errors.map(err => {
                return(<li key={err}>{err}</li>);
            })}</ul>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Perhaps this is similar?  https://stackoverflow.com/a/38612078/3662110  Sounds like the browser can't handle all the requests.  Maybe these requests can be made from the backend?

Comment: If you're making 500 requests, it's probably best to move this to middleware that can process all of this, cache it, then access it through the browser using one single API call. That many back-and-forth trips on a browser is really bad news for users, not only for memory but latency.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend handling all of this logic on the server side. It will be extremely difficult to scale this application as is, should the need arise.

Instead of making 500 different requests from the browser, make 1 single request, and only return the `meaningful` data to the client.

This will reduce network latency in a big way, and also reduce memory consumption as well.